# Construct an embedding

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I'm dealing with this problem from the book "Field Theory" (Steven Roman)

Suppose $F$ and $E$ are fields and $\sigma : F \rightarrow E $ is an embedding. Construct an extension of $F$ that is isomorphic to $E$.

How can we extend?

Comment: What *exactly* is the definition of extension here? One could say that $E$ itself *is* an extension of $F$ that is isomorphic to $E$. (And I'm having a hard time coming up with a definition that excludes $E$ itself being an extension of $F$, but still allows me to construct some extension of $F$. )

Comment: Maybe the point is to take $E' := F \cup (E \setminus \sigma(F))$ (and give it the same field structure as $E$). Then it really *contains* $F$.

Answer (score 0):

It may probably be something about the extension of embeddings. Namely,
if you extend $\sigma$ to $\sigma$$^-$ you will get the extension

$\sigma $$(F)$$\lt $ $\sigma$$^-$$(E)$

And note that $\sigma$ is a monomorphism and you will get $E$ isomorphic to  $\sigma$$^-$$(E)$.

However, it may not be that much easy, needs some comment.

Comment: In this question we must find an extension $F'$ of $F$ that naturally extends $\sigma$ in such a way $\overline{\sigma}:F'\rightarrow E$ is surjective.

Comment: instead of $\sigma(F)<\overline{\sigma}(E)$ we must say that if $F'$ is an extension of $F$ then $\sigma(F)<\overline{\sigma}(F')<E$

Answer (score 0):

Then all I can say about $F'$ is that it may be exactly $(\sigma^-)^{-1} (E)$, which definitely is isomorphic to E.